# Use bluetooth call audio as speaker audio with Roger Pen

Tags: bluetooth, audio, lg

I have a [Roger Pen](https://www.phonakpro.com/au/en/products/wireless-accessories/roger-pen/overview-roger-pen.html) that is linked to my LG G5 via bluetooth to answer phone calls. I am told that the pen can only answer and end calls via bluetooth, but if I want to play music through my pen, I have to connect it via a audio cable with a micro usb adapter.

This set up to play music is a little daunting, especially with a small cable dangling with my phone. So I was wondering if it is possible to route music through the bluetooth call audio function?

On the profiles for the Roger Pen on bluetooth settings, there is only the Call audio setting enabled. I was wondering if there was an app to override this?

[image]

Comment: Update: Found out there is an app called MonoBT that might do the trick, but I have lost my phone G5 and so I will be getting a G6 soon.